# Google App Engine inter module communication authorization

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Communication_between_modules) it says

> You can configure any manual or basic scaling module to accept requests from other modules in your app by restricting its handler to only allow administrator accounts, specifying login: admin for the appropriate handler in the module's configuration file. With this restriction in place, any URLFetch from any other module in the app will be automatically authenticated by App Engine, and any request that is not from the application will be rejected.

so i did that, but unfortunately it does not work. I am requesting a url from module A on module B which is protected by the `login: admin` property

I can fetch that url in the browser which shows me the login page and after i continue as admin i can fetch my route.

How is it supposed to work? As far as i understand it should add a header to the request which includes some kind of authorization token.

If i fetch that same url within a request on module A i get the same redirect. `urllib2` follows the `302` status code by default and the result is the login page.

I am running the environment using the `gcloud preview app run` command. Module A is a default module and module B is a [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/) Container, might this be the problem here?

Comment: can you share the relevant module configuration and the call to fetch? Also, did you try running module B as a regular module instead of as a Managed VM?

Comment: everything works beside the fact that if i put the authentication on it redirects the request to the login page. I could try running it as a module (or at least the relevant code) to narrow it down to the vm

Comment: yes, please add the code and try to isolate the problem, as it would be much easier to help you that way :)

Comment: Did it work when the app is deployed?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem here, and I'm getting a 302 (HTTP) as result of the call:
`result = urlfetch.fetch(url,
                            follow_redirects=False,
                            method=urlfetch.POST,
                            payload=payload,
                            headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})`
I don't get it since it should be already logged in as admin since the call is coming from another module. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: if you remove the `follow_redirects=False` you will be redirected to the login page i guess, i did not solve the issue yet, simply removed the  `login:admin`property for development. Havent tested in production altough

Comment: I tested it in production, with the same settings, and it doesn't work. Unfortunately for me it can't be a solution removing the `login:admin`property, and I'm struggling to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Hey all, as you can read in my answer below, inspecting headers is the best way to ensure the request came from your app, short of implementing more robust security on your own via headers, salted hashes of request data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this is occurring, and I've reproduced the issue. The issue is being tracked over in the [App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12069). Follow there for any updates.

For now, I think it's much better to be manually-inspecting the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header, as this is managed by the infrastructure and can't be spoofed.

You could also implement OAuth, but that adds overhead you may not want or need on a small app.

Comment: i tried to check the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` but unfortunately it does not exist on the devserver. Currently i have no idea how to protect my routes on the Managed VM

Comment: I did set the `follow_redirects=False` and the problem is the same for the `/_ah/start' and `/_ah/stop` handlers

Comment: As far as inspecting X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid, yes, this should only be checked in production since it's managed by the infrastructure. If you don't expose your ports to the external world, or at the very least don't advertise your public IP, you'll be either completely secure or secure by obscurity (for each case, respectively)

Comment: follow_redirects is for preventing urlfetch from automatically following-up on 3xx redirect responses, and I don't see any reason why that would help with this issue. As said above, use headers in production, and secure your dev environment from outside requests.