# App Engine Flexible + App Identity (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Is there a way to port the functionality of

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

in the flexible environment?

I have a service running on the flex environment which needs to make a request to the standard environment and would like to use App Engine's native app identity and `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header to do so.

It seems that if the origin of the request is from the standard environment, the header is passed on to the flex environment but not the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** It is not possible to use the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header in this case because, as you observed, it is removed on the ingress side of the standard env service after being specifically set on the egress side of the flexible env service, following the suggested experiment:

Original post:

From [App identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#app_identity):

> When running on the flexible environment, you can use a combination of
>   [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#environment_variables) and the [Google Compute Engine Metadata
>   service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to obtain information about your application:
>
> Application / project ID
>
> Either the **GCLOUD_PROJECT** environment variable or
>   the **/project/project-id** resource in the metadata server

So you could try to get the app ID in the flex env service as mentioned above and manually set the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` response header. It *might* not be removed on the ingress side of the standard env service (it's not explicitly mentioned to be removed in [Request headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#request-headers)).

As for the urlfetch porting, from [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#url_fetch):

> The flexible environment has no sandbox restrictions, so you can use
>   any HTTP library. We recommend using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

So check for the specific method to set the response header for whichever HTTP library you decide to use.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the quick answer. I've tried this method actual and manually set the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` using the python requests library. However it seems that once the request is received by the standard environment, this header is stripped.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I updated the answer to reflect your verification.

Comment: I was going to also suggest isolating the handler for that specific URL and protecting it with `login: admin` in the std env service's `.yaml` file, but it seems it's not effective, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237946/google-app-engine-inter-module-communication-authorization#comment49814138_30237946

Comment: I did consider the login:admin as well but unless the urlfetch library can be imported and used directly in the flex environment, this seems ineffective as you've mentioned as the standard env would just cause a redirect to an authorization page. For now, I've used something similar to an OAuth token to help secure the request.

Comment: Yep, such token would work. Complicates things a bit, but there doesn't appear to be an alternative presently.