# Google App Engine services communicating and available on internal network only

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to make Google App Engine services only available on a Google Cloud internal network, and if so, how? I have some microservices that shouldn't be publicly available (for use by other services only).

I know you can configure firewalls, however:

- The app engine firewalls apply to all services
- I have no idea what IP range to allow for app engine services with the VPC, since app engine works with domains only, and doesn't specify what range it uses.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using standard environment services you might be able to use the app ID to validate requests in such services. From [Asserting identity to other App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps):

> If you want to determine the identity of the App Engine app that is
>   making a request to your App Engine app, you can use the request
>   header `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid`. This header is added to the
>   request by the URLFetch service and is not user modifiable, so it
>   safely indicates the requesting application's ID, if present.
>
> In order for this header to be added to the request, the app making
>   the request must tell the URLFetch service to not follow redirects.
>   That is, it must set the `fetch` [`follow_redirects`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch) parameter to
>   `False`. App Engine will then automatically add the header to the HTTP
>   response.
>
> In your application handler, you can check the incoming ID by reading
>   the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header and comparing it to a list of
>   IDs allowed to make requests.
>
> ```
> **Note:** The **X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid** header is only set if the call
> is made to the **appspot.com** domain. If the app has a custom domain, 
> this header will not be set.
> ```

If however you're using the flex environment this approach doesn't work, see [App Engine Flexible + App Identity (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355236/app-engine-flexible-app-identity-python/46355506#46355506)

Using authentication with the app's own service account could be another thing to look at for the flex environment - but I didn't try it yet. See [Service Account for the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/service-account).

Comment: Thanks for the Trouble I am using a mix of flex and standard, so I guess I'll need a solution that caters for both.