# 'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid' header is not set when using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, google-flexible

I have two services running on the Google App Engine (MS1 & MS2). MS1 is deployed in the Standard Environment and MS2 is deployed in the Flexible Environment. I am invoking an API from Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment. I want to make sure that MS2 only accepts requests originating from MS1. So, I decided to use [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps) feature from App Engine. I am setting the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header and `setInstanceFollowRedirects` to `false` in MS1, but looks like App Engine is removing this header. I am not able to find this header in MS2.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid", ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId());
HttpEntity<MergePdfsResource> entity = new HttpEntity<MergePdfsResource>(mergePdfsResource, headers);

restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    }
});

ResponseEntity<SomeClass> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(apiUrl, entity, SomeClass.class);
```

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355236/app-engine-flexible-app-identity-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is the answer I got from the Google Support:

The `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header is set only if we are using the URLFetch service. In the java8 runtime environment, the default is `native` which uses the standard Java network classes. So, I had to set the URL stream handler to `urlfetch` in `appengine-web.xml` as below:

```
<url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
```